# EBean : Why does bindFromRequest() return null values?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, persistence, ebean

I'm using Play framework with Sqlite.

I've created a model - Bar

(contents of app/models/Bar.java)

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class Bar extends Model{

    @Id
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public Bar(String id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }
    public Bar(){}

    public static Finder<String, Bar> find = new Finder(String.class, Bar.class);

}
```

And I'm trying to add bars by form submit :

```
public static Result addBar(){
    Form<Bar> form = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest();
    Bar bar = form.get();
    bar.save();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());

}
```

But, both id and name in bar here is null. 
Please help me understand why is this happening?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of `ebean.default` in your `application.conf` file ?

Comment: ebean.default="models.*"

Comment: Then try renaming the package of `Bar` to `models` instead of `model`

Comment: @Chafik Did that. Not getting that error anymore :) But form.get() has null values! What else am I missing here?

Comment: I made a complete answer, you can accept it if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question for future users :

If in the `application.conf` file, the Ebean configuration is `ebean.default="models.*"` then the package that contains the models has to be `models` and not `model`.

Regarding the other question (`form.get()` being null), after binding your form from the request, you need to make sure it has no errors :

```
public static Result addBar() {
    Form<Bar> form = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        // Do something with the errors (i.e. : redirect with flash message containing the main error)
    }
    Bar bar = form.get();
    bar.save();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```